# Cant remove docker images on azure, gives "Error: No such image"

Tags: azure, docker

I can't remove docker images on azure, and I have run out of storage space.

I login to

```
$ ssh -i nopass.pem -fNL LOCAL_PORT:localhost:REMOTE_PORT -p 2200 [USERNAME]@[DNSPREFIX]mgmt.[REGION].cloudapp.azure.com
```

and then I can see a bunch of images with

```
$ docker -H 127.0.0.1:22375 images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                     IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
whatever.azurecr.io/whatnot   2018_01_08_12_0db3a68   7c3ea6fa5131        6 weeks ago         1.38GB
whatever.azurecr.io/whatnot   2018_01_08_11_8978ed3   e168b18d0057        6 weeks ago         1.38GB
whatever.azurecr.io/whatnot   2018_01_04_11_4147403   2ad5bc1170d0        6 weeks ago         1.39GB
whatever.azurecr.io/whatnot   2018_01_02_12_785ec5e   0e8d0954009b        7 weeks ago         1.39GB
whatever.azurecr.io/whatnot   2018_01_02_11_785ec5e   f8f33d1350c9        7 weeks ago         1.39GB
```

But when I try to remove them

```
$ docker -H 127.0.0.1:22375 rmi 7c3ea6fa5131
Error: No such image: 7c3ea6fa5131
```

Can someone advice what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up logging in to swarm master, and from there I logged into the swarm-agent with:

`ssh -i nopass.pem [USERNAME]@10.0.0.5`

The ip-address to the swarm-agent I found at portal.azure.com

From the swarm-agent I could do

`docker rmi 7c3ea6fa5131`

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into this problem on azure and am not sure what causes it. Try a `docker system prune` if you can afford to lose your images and volumes not currently being used. If you can, also try restarting docker. The combination of those two steps worked for me.